# Is $x_1=1$ and $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(x_n+\frac{2}{x_n})$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let be $(x_n)$ a sequence defined by $x_1=1$ and $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(x_n+\frac{2}{x_n})$.

$(x_n)$ is increasing or decreasing? I do not know if $(x_n)$ is bounded. I would like to know if $(x_n)$ is convergent. Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you know the sequence is increasing? The fact that it's increasing, if true, actually _implies_ an upper bound! Increasing says $(x_n+2/x_n)/2\ge x_n$ and if you boil that down a bit an upper bound pops out.

Comment: Compute a few values: $x_1=1$ $x_2=1.5$, $x_3 = 1.41667$, $x_4 = 1.41422$. From this we see that the seqeunce is not increasing, but it looks like it's decreasing starting from $x_2$.

Comment: This scheme is the [Babylonian method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method) to compute $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: How do you know it's increasing or decreasing?

Answer (score 0):

Oups! I thought that the post was saying that the sequence in increasing... Sorry for this. To make things clear I will provide full solution.

We will show that $(x_n)$ is ${\bf decreasing}$ and bounded from below by $\sqrt{2}$ from the second term and after and that $\lim_n x_n=\sqrt{2}.$

$x_1=1,$ $x_2=\frac{3}{2}>\sqrt{2}.$ Let $x_n\geq \sqrt{2}$ for some $n\geq 2$ (induction hypothesis).

Then $x_{n+1}\geq \sqrt{2}\;\Leftrightarrow\;x_{n+1}^2\geq 2\;\Leftrightarrow\;(x_n+\frac{2}{x_n})^2\geq 8\;\Leftrightarrow\;(x_n-\frac{2}{x_n})^2\geq 0,$ which holds.

We have showed that $x_n\geq \sqrt{2}\;\forall\;n\geq 2.$

Let $n\geq 2.$  $x_{n+1}\leq x_n\;\Leftrightarrow\;\frac{1}{2}(x_n+\frac{2}{x_n})\leq x_n\;\Leftrightarrow\;\frac{2}{x_n}\leq x_n\;\Leftrightarrow\;2\leq x_n^2,$ which is true for any $n\geq 2.$

So, $(x_n)$ is convergent to $\inf_n x_n\geq \sqrt{2}.$

If $\lim_n x_{n+1}=\lim_n x_n=x,$ the inductive formula gives $x^2=2,$ hence $x=\sqrt{2},$ since $x>0.$

This is actually a formula due to Newton in order to approximate (from above) the number $\sqrt{2}.$ More generally, for any $\alpha>0,$ if you set $x_1$ to be any positive number, say $x_1=1,$ and then $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(x_n+\frac{a}{x_n}),$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N},$ you can show that for $n\geq 2$ the sequence in decreasing and that it is bounded from below by $\sqrt{a},$ hence converges (by the same reasoning, to $\sqrt{a}).$

Comment: Actually $x_n$ isn't increasing...

Comment: No, you can't _show_ that the sequence is increasing or decreasing by _assuming_ it has a limit.

Comment: "Now pick any number $\alpha \geq \sqrt{2}$ and show (easily with induction) that $x_n\leq \alpha$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}.$" Sorry but there exists some $\alpha>\sqrt2$ such that this is not true (and this *even less true* for $\alpha=\sqrt2$...).

Comment: @Wojowu Yes, I edited. I thought that OP had posted that he had already proved that the sequence was decreasing.

Comment: @David Yes, you can do it (at some cases!). Note that if you have an inductive formula of a sequence and you show that the sequence is monotone, then if you ${\bf assume}$ that it converges, say to $x$ and you can find $x$ from the inductive formula, then you can show that the sequence is bounded from below (if the sequence is decreasing) or from above (if the sequence is increasing) by $x.$ Remember that a convergent increasing sequence (decreasing resp.) converges to the $\sup$ of the terms ($\inf$ of the terms resp.).

Comment: @Did. See the updated post. What I initially wrote is true for any $\alpha\leq \sqrt{2}.$

Comment: No, "what you initially wrote" is not true either "for any $\alpha\leqslant\sqrt2$"... but this is no big deal since you now entirely revised the answer.

Comment: Your comment "if ... you show that the sequence is monotone, then if you _assume_ that it converges, say to $x$ and you can find $x$ from the inductive formula, then you can show that the sequence is bounded from below" has absolutely no relevance to what I said, that you can't show a sequence is monotone by assuming it has a limit.